# UISegmentedControl fires ValueChanged when loading selectedindex

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISplitViewController` utility type app where each `UIViewController` handles various calculations. I have a popover with segmented controls that allows the user to set certain options. The problem I have is when saving and reloading the contents of `UITextfields` and the selected segment index, if the segment control index was saved and is == 1 a valuechanged event is fired off from `viewdidload` as the state is set from

```
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   theDepthSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = [[defaults objectForKey:@"updateMe"] intValue];
```

Is there anyway to prevent valuechanged being fired as the selectedsegment is set in view did load? or maybe someway to determine the difference between touch events versus code

It seems strange this happens, maybe there is another way....

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the view is just loading, the segmented control doesn't have a previous value, so it will assume it is indeed being changed and acts accordingly.  One way you could potentially get around this is to set up a `BOOL` value in your `IBAction` method linked to the segmented control.  At the beginning of your `viewDidLoad` method, say `wasLoaded = NO` (where `wasLoaded` will need to be declared in your header file).  Then you'll assign your `selectedSegmentIndex`.  Afterwards, declare `wasLoaded = YES`.  Finally, in your `IBAction` method, say something like

```
if (wasLoaded) { 
    // do what you need to do since this isn't when it's being initialized 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to get this done is to detach the `IBAction` in the interface builder and add a `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method after you change the value in `viewDidLoad`. There is no way of making a distinction between touch triggered change and a programmatic change for `UIControlEventValueChanged`. You can look at touch control events but it is not the same as the value changed one.

Answer (score 0):

Deepak is right. If you're not using Interface Builder to setup your `UISegmentedControl`, you should first set the selected index of the `UISegmentedControl` and then call `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`. Like this:

```
            NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", nil];
            UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:items];
            [items release];
            [segmentedControl setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 46.0f)];
            [segmentedControl setTag:60];
            [segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:savedSelectedIndex];
            [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segControlClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
            [segmentedControl release];
```